# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse$Configuration$Builder on below Lollipop versions

Tags: android, parse-platform, noclassdeffounderror, android-multidex

I am using parse.com sdk in my app. **It is working absolutely fine with Lollipop**. But when I run the app on below lollipop versions I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse$Configuration$Builder
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:297)
at com.xxx.android.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:16)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4747)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm getting this error when initialising parse by

```
Parse.initialize(this);
```

Application class code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this);
}
```

}

My manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.android">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.xxx.android.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxx.android.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/client_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/api_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.android"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.18'

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the min SDK in your app?

Comment: Do you have multidex enabled?

Comment: Yes I have enabled multidex. Should I post full app gradle code?

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks.

Comment: Added full gradle file code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your dependencies and since you have confirmed you have multidex enabled, please consider this (quoting from the official documentation):

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library.

It means you have to set the multidex support library in order to enable multidex and to be able to run your application on devices running a version of Android prior to 5.0.

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) is quite straightforward and it's really simple to follow.

You basically have to:

- enable multidex support in your `defaultConfig` section adding: `multiDexEnabled true`
- declare the library as a dependency:

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
- skip the step where you have to set `MultiDexApplication` in the manifest as the `application` name (because you have your own `Application` class).

Since you have a custom `Application` class, please be careful while you set the multidex support library:

> If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the
>   attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable
>   multidex.

So call this method from your custom `Application` class.

Please check if there's a new version of the library: Android Studio should give you a warning if that's the case.

Comment: Great! Happy coding ;)