# Parse NoClassDef error

Tags: android, parse-platform

On android 4.1-4.4 im getting a lot of app crashes. It has to do with the initilization of parse and it only affects these android versions, it works perfect on 5.0-6.0. The logcat error is below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse$Configuration$Builder
   at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:364)
   at com.intellidev.faucetpro2.lll.onCreate(lll.java:62)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.intellidev.faucetpro2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.3.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/supersonic/android-sdk"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':appgrade')
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.sharegov:mjson:1.3'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.3.6@jar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:0.0.9'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.intellidev.faucetpro2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.playerize.superrewards.activities.SRWebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:862222248463" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

<!--                   IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.intellidev.faucetpro" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.appgrade.sdk.view.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

        <!-- Component that rewarded ADs needs -->
        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.ExpService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
        <!-- Optional Component -->
        <receiver android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse$Configuration$Builder on below Lollipop versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876628/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-parse-parseconfigurationbuilder-on-below-l)

Comment: @fillobotto i tried this but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue very recently, it is one of the worst thing that can happen to a parser.

This is merely because of outdated SDKs. I have literally spent weeks with this issue and I solved it by **updating all the SDKs for versions below Lollipop**!

You may do a **clean install of Android studio and freshly download the SDKs** **if** the **first solution doesn't work**. ( I tried this on a new machine and it worked for me)

Comment: can you give more detail into what you did?

Comment: i've highlighted the important part of the anwser!

Comment: and by the way u should consider moving away from parse as fast as possible!

Comment: as you can see in my gradle i am using the lastest version of the sdks

Comment: I meant updating the SDKs from the SDK Manager of Android Studio, updates are released for Older versions of APIs as well. Like for API version 19, google will have released a new update. I suggest u to try updating these APIs. Then u may try testing on Devices running on Kitkat or as such.

Comment: All my sdks are up to date.

Comment: Can u please update your question with the screenshot of the same?